# How can i access data from parent repeater in nested repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Use modelbinding to pass a list of **Post Objects** containing *post id*,*Title*.. to my page.aspx

Each **Post Objects** also contains a list of **Comment Objects** and these are

the ones i want to access in the inner repeater.

Here the code from my **page.aspx**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1" ItemType="OOPBLOG.Model.Classes.Post" 
    SelectMethod="LoadPosts"
    OnCallingDataMethods="postView">

    <ItemTemplate >
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Item.Title %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Item.Body %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Item.Date %></td>
        </tr>         
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                  <%# ((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).ItemType %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

To conclude, what i want, is to access the *Item.Comments* List in the nested repeater. How can i do this?

Comment: what you tried you can access it in ItemBound

Comment: Could you give an example of that?